# Compile multi .hs files of Haskell - Unix

Tags: unix, haskell, ghc, ghci

I created some files from a project in Unix, they are a lot and if I want to execute it in another pc or folder I need to copy all files to there. They are all connected in *import*.
How can I make an executable haskell program?

I have per example:

```
main.hs - main where all the program executes; using,besides haskell, unix shell.
ex1.hs - basically types of data, some functions.
ex2.lhs - same as ex1.lhs but is literate with LaTeX
pic.jpg - picture to use on the pdflatex
package.sty - package needed to use some functions
```

How do I proceed and compile all of these?
I tried using *ghc* but always giving errors:

```
>ghc -o MAIN main.hs ex1.hs ex2.lhs pic.jpg package.sty
```

`Failed to load interface for 'ex1.hs'`
And is in the line which has **import ex1.hs**

Curious is if I trade **import ex1.hs** to **import ex2.lhs** line will give error on ex2

Comment: How do you want a `.jpg`- or `.sty`-file to be compiled? Should it be embedded into the executable?

Comment: Yes I need it cause the program creates a pdf and I need that jpg and sty is a package

Comment: Is this a project created by somebody else? If so, is there a Makefile or similar?

Comment: No, I created it. I just need to make an executable

Comment: Give us enough details to reproduce your problem. Post some code, the command you tried, and the errors you got.

Comment: Do you mean `main.hs` or `main.lhs` or is the first file really called `main.h`? And for `ex1.h`? Are they (literate?) Haskell source files, C header files, or what?

Comment: Edited, lhs are literate with latex yes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Haskell module names must begin with an upper case letter, so start by renaming `ex1.hs` and `ex2.hs` to `Ex1.hs` and `Ex2.hs`. They should also start with `module Ex1 where`, otherwise the module name will default to `Main`, and GHC will be very confused when the module names don't match the file names.
2. Import statements should refer to the module name, not the file name, so change them in `main.hs` to correspond to the module names.

   ```
   import Ex1
   import Ex2
   ```
3. Now compile with `ghc --make main.hs`, and it should find the other modules automatically. It will search for modules with both `.hs` and `.lhs` extensions, and correctly treat the latter like literate Haskell files.

For larger projects, you should look into using [Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/), the build system used by most Haskell libraries and programs. It will help with managing dependencies and compiler options, sort of like a Makefile.

Comment: I had all right with names, using that _ghc --make main.hs_ works but it makes .o files and the picture isn't compiled.
Then how can I execute it? cause _./main.o_ or _./main_ won't work

Comment: @GoodGuyGreg: Assuming the compilation succeeded, `./main` should work. I'm confused about the compiling the picture part. Are you talking about LaTeX compilation?

Comment: Yes, it compiles a pdf in a funtion, but if it is impossible to compile a jpg I can remove it no problem, but the problem is when I compile i makes .o files to each .hs and .lhs imported in main.hs and ./main says it don't exist

Comment: @GoodGuyGreg: Can you join me in [the Haskell chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4064/haskell)? This sounds like it might be easier to resolve interactively.

Answer (score 3):

Try

`ghc --make main.hs`

That should make ghc try to do everything it can...